# mod_rewrite - simple redirect to parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I need is to redirect everything from a certain directory to the index file of the parent directory. The URL in the browser has to change as well, just straight redurect. How do I do this? I tried variations of

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ ../ [R]
```

but it displays an error and the actual system path!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most easily accomplished by using an absolute http URL:

```
# We assume this is in .htaccess inside the directory to be redirected
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent 
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/parent [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Note, `QSA` was added to preserve the query string, but that can be removed if you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks, that kinda works, although using absolute URLs blows. Also, since the parent directory uses URL rewriting as well, and uses RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?where=$1 [QSA,L], when the URL is redirected by what you wrote, it's redirected to http://host/parent/?where=child

Comment: @DMIL RewriteCond added above to inhibit the rewrite loop.

Comment: Doesn't work with RewriteCond, works without RewriteCond line, although absolute URLs are a big problem. Also, works differently if the trailing slash of child is omitted, then it shows the redirect from parent. ** Edit: Actually it seems that RewriteCond line doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @DMIL the slash can be removed from the `(.*)/` group. I hadn't noticed it there, and that should solve the behavior problem

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't have any effect. I'm confused by your answers but I don't have time to figure this out. It kinda works and that's good enough, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/child/?$ http://example.com/
```

Comment: Where would I put this? In the parent directory .htaccess? Where exactly, before or after the rewrite rules for the parent directory? Also, it doesn't work. The URL it redirects to is http://hostname/parent/child instead of http://hostname/parent

Comment: It should be in the current directory.  It shouldn't matter where at in the .htaccess file it is.